# How do I construct an array of ctype structures?

Tags: python, ctypes

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> class A(Structure):
...  _fields_ = [('a', c_int), ('b', c_int)]
...  def __init__(self, x):
...   self.a = x + 1
...   self.b = x + 2
... 
>>> a = A(1)
>>> a.a
2
>>> a.b
3
>>> b = (A * 2)(1, 2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: expected A instance, got int
```

I am trying to construct an array of C structures in python and want the constructor to be called for each element in the array. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error explains exactly the problem, but in a slightly convoluted manner:

The correct way to initialize such an array is as follows:

```
structs = [A(1, 2), A(1, 2)]
array = (A * 2)(*structs)
```

Or, if you can define them all during the array constructor, as follows:

```
array = (A * 2)(A(1, 2), A(1, 2))
```

Now, why does this work and your solution not? Since I am passing an **instance** of `A` for each argument to the constructor of `A * 2`, which is an array of `A`. The array requires an instance of `A` for each argument passed, which is precisely the error message. It does not expect to convert arguments into `A`, it expects an instance of `A` itself.

The step-by-step way is as follows:

```
from ctypes import *
class A(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('a', c_int), ('b', c_int)]

# this create a class which expects 2 A instances
a_array_factory = A * 2
# our first A instance
struct_1 = A(1, 2)
# our second A instance
struct_2 = A(2, 3)
# initialize our array
array = a_array_factory(struct_1, struct_2)
```

EDIT:

Since a structure does not have a native Python type, there is no solution, to my knowledge, without creating intermediary structs. According to the Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#fundamental-data-types), the only native types with C primitives are the following:

```
ctypes type     C type                                      Python type
c_bool          _Bool                                       bool (1)
c_char          char                                        1-character string
c_wchar         wchar_t                                     1-character unicode string
c_byte          char                                        int/long
c_ubyte         unsigned char                               int/long
c_short         short                                       int/long
c_ushort        unsigned short                              int/long
c_int           int                                         int/long
c_uint          unsigned int                                int/long
c_long          long                                        int/long
c_ulong         unsigned long                               int/long
c_longlong      __int64 or long long                        int/long
c_ulonglong     unsigned __int64 or unsigned long long      int/long
c_float         float                                       float
c_double        double                                      float
c_longdouble    long double                                 float
c_char_p        char * (NUL terminated)                     string or None
c_wchar_p       wchar_t * (NUL terminated)                  unicode or None
c_void_p        void *                                      int/long or Nonee or None
```

Comment: That makes sense ! But there will be an extra intermediate object created for each object in the array. Is there any way to avoid that ? I find that the following works:
    a = (c_int * 2)(1, 2)
So, python interpretor is treating this as equivalent to:
    a = (c_int * 2)(c_int(1), c_int(2))

Comment: `c_int` has a logical Pythonic type (int). A struct does not. So no. Only values in this table, to my knowledge, can be logically converted (I'll add it to the post):
https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#fundamental-data-types

Comment: @Rahul, `struct_1` and `struct_2` are only used to construct `array`, which has its own buffer. It's basically no different from `(c_int * 2)(1, 2)`, which constructs an array from `int` objects 1 and 2. The temporary `struct_1` and `struct_2` objects can be discarded after the array is constructed. If you have an existing object with a writeable buffer interface, you can use `(A * 2).from_buffer(x)` to avoid temporary objects and copying. The buffer of `x` must be at least `sizeof(A * 2)` bytes.

Comment: @eryksun, I am writing a python wrapper over a C library. There are a huge number of functions of the form:
void func(size_t count, struct abc *obj);
So, copying from a buffer is not useful for me. The C library has been designed to be high performing and the structures used are pretty big and nested. So, I am trying to avoid unnecessary intermediate objects as much as possible so as to keep the performance degradation to a minimum.

Comment: @Rahul, you can also initialize an array using tuples, e.g. `(A * 2)((1, 2), (3, 4))`, but that's not gaining much in terms efficiency, since internally ctypes constructs a temporary object using each tuple.

Comment: @eryksun, quick profiling in iPython shows it's no more efficient for that reason.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh, I was trying to avoid doing that in the interest of keeping the number of lines of code to a minimum :) But if there is no other way, I may end up doing that.

Comment: @Rahul The only real way to know is profiling the app. If the C API is computationally intensive, you likely will not notice the conversion times for each call. Either way, good luck ^_^